# Trying to put {MyDocuments} in Settings.settings

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm trying to set a default folder for my program when it starts for the first time and want to use My Documents. The way I store the folder the user wants to use is in the Settings.settings file.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to find out the user's My Documents folder and put it in the Settings.settings table so that it is default.

I tried a few variations of **{MyDocuments}** but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT**

Hey guys, thanks for the awesomely quick responses, the problem is I want to put it into Settings.settings, is the only way to check if this is the first time the program has been run with a bool or something and then swap out the value of my Settings.settings row with the code you've given below?

Is there no way to put it straight into the settings.settings table?

Comment: Maybe this will help: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the User My Document folder use this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

*Update*

You can use this one in your **code**:

```
string applicationPath = Settings.Default.UserPath;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPath ))
{
   applicationPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
}
```

The idea is pretty clear - you check the `Settings` if its not OK you initialize it with the value you need.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing thanks, I wish there was a way to just put something like "{MyDocuments}" in Settings.settings though so we didn't have to write one-off code.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the path to they `MyDocuments` folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Comment: @Nolonar - I dont think so. I have posted it also the same time and havent seen your comment

Comment: @MikroDel I said "looks like", not "is", but I'm cool with that. I just thought it would be too short for a proper answer and since I've never used that code, I wasn't sure if it was correct either.

Comment: @Nolonar Sorry it it looks like that! But can I write something different after seeing that you wrote the comment a few seconds before my answer?

Comment: @Nolonar - than I agree with you ) But its also looks like your comment is copy & paste of my or MD.Unicorn answer. Looks like not is )

Comment: @MD.Unicorn No, I'm cool with that, really. I didn't make it an answer because I wasn't sure it'd work (I've never used that code before)

Comment: @Nolonar I always have a sample project open in VisualStudio. I write my answer inside it, test it, and post it to SO. This way I'm sure that it is correct :-)